# VBScript from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word, ctrl

I hope someone can please help me with this. The VB script below is in Excel and creates a new Word document. The code will copy a picture from Excel into Word. Then it will create and position a TextBox over the picture. It will then put text in the TextBox. This code does work correctly.

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture1").Copy
wrdApp.Selection.Paste


With wrdDoc.Shapes.AddTextBox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 150, 96, 50)
    .Select
    .Name = "TextBox1"
End With


With wrdApp.Selection
    .ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = 0
    .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = 0
    .TypeText Text:="My picture text"
End With
```

As mentioned, the above code does work. The problem is I need to put this in a loop to copy the picture again (an X number of times). When I write the code to put it in a loop, it will paste the additional picture within the TextBox because that was last selected. I somehow need to code something like the Ctrl + End keys so it will bring the curser to the end of the document and outside of the TextBox. I can't get that to work.

In order to do that I need to use this code:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
```

So the proper place to insert it within the code should be this section, like what I have below:

```
With wrdApp.Selection
    .ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = 0
    .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = 0
    .TypeText Text:="My picture text"
    .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
End With
```

This gives me a VB error when I add that line in. Now if I copy this code into Word and run it from the Macro, it will work perfectly. However, this code is in Excel and has to create everything in Word.

Can someone please tell me how I can get it so it moves the curser out of the TextBox and to the end of the document? I know the issue is because the code is in Excel and trying to go to Word, there has to be some way to get it to work or a similar code using ASCII. I have tried everything I can think of and searched for hours for a solution.

Thanks for any help someone can provide,

Chris

Comment: How about to call macro in Word from within Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this works for me:

```
With wrdapp.ActiveDocument
  .Range(.Range.Characters.Count, .Range.Characters.Count).Select
End With
```

**Edit**

Try this (add stuff, remove stuff, see what works):

```
With wrdapp.ActiveDocument
  .Range(.Range.Characters.Count, .Range.Characters.Count).Select
  .GoTo wdgotobookmark, name:="\EndOfDoc"
  Selection.Move wdCharacter, .Characters.Count
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mkingston! That works perfectly! Genius, I would never have come up with that.

Comment: Haha I might not go as far as genius. Actually, no, I'll take it. Happy to help :).

Comment: Hi mkingston, your code works perfectly when I am only doing one instance, but when I put it in a loop, so it copies more than one picture to a document creating the TextBox for each picture, the code will place the cursor before the picture (for each picture after the 1st one). So with the 1st picture/TextBox set the code works (placing the cursor at the end of the document, after the picture). Then when it loops to make a 2nd set, the cursor goes to the front of each set after that. I need the cursor to always be placed at the very end of the document each time. Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I also tried to implement the idea that Tolga gave after your code. This worked well when I stepped through the code, but when running normally the problem with the SendKeys is that it is too slow. The code runs faster than the SendKeys function, so other code is being run while the SendKeys is still being processed. The other issue with SendKeys is that it turns off the numb lock key on the keyboard each time it is run.

Comment: Hi mkingston thanks for the information. I get an error on both of the additional lines. Stepping through it receives an error on line wdgotobookmark and the line after. I never heard of wdgotobookmark but really like it, I looked it up. I think the error is due to this code being in Excel and not Word. When it is in Excel it doesn't captialize the letters it leaves it as wdgotobookmark, if it was recoginsed it would correct it to look like this wdGoToBookmark. I will keep looking to see if I can find how to use this in excel, please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify that: normally values you pass to a function like that are constants. They're given a variable name so they're easier for you to remember/use/interpret. In word, if you go to the VB Editor and press Ctrl+G to display the immediate window, then in that window type `? wdGoToBookmark` the result will be -1. I suggest you test to see what some similar constants in Excel are, using the immediate window, just to get an idea of what I mean (the numerical values of the constants are normally irrelevant).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for that info. I didn't know about the constant thing or pressing Ctrl+G. Is there a command I can type in that will list all of the constants, sort of like typing "help" in Command Prompt? If I could get a full list for what I can use, that would be very helpful. I assume though, now that I know to look for Excel constants, I can probably search the Internet for that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That's ok, did you replace the code? Did it work? To the best of my knowledge, the closest to a list of constants you'll find is the Object Browser. To view it press F2 in the VB Editor.

Comment: Hi mkingston, I just got back into work, but I was playing with this a bit over the weekend and I thought I figured out the solution, but wanted to wait until I got back to work to confirm it. This does work. I only need one line, it is "wrdDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select". I could not have figured that out on my own, you pointed me to that direction. This does work perfectly. Thank you so for your time and knowledge that you shared with me!

Comment: No problem, it was mostly experimentation rather than knowledge, but I'm happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Though this might not be the ideal way to go, the code below will clear the selection in Word, moving the focus out of the textbox.

```
wrdApp.Activate
SendKeys "{ESC}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tolga Ozudogru, I don't get any errors but this still keeps the text box selected. The answer that mkingston provided works great. I appreciate the reply though.

Comment: Actually, correction to my last comment. This does work and I was so close to doing this before. My sytax was just slightly off. Here is how it needs to be in order for what I need: 
wrdApp.Activate 
SendKeys "^{END}"
Thanks again Tolga Ozudogru!